# How do I add next page break to FPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am using FPDF library to convert the contents of my database to PDF. However, I am unable to paginate to the next page when the first page of the pdf is filled. This ends up displaying the contents wrongly. How do I add a new page or how do I go about it? Anyone?

```
<?php
ob_start();
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

//Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
$result= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customer");

$number_of_products = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Initialize the  columns and the total
$column_id = "";
$column_name = "";
$column_trans_id = "";
$column_amount = "";

//For each row, add the field to the corresponding column
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $trans_id = substr($row["trans_id"],0,20);
    $amount = $row["amount"];

    $column_id = $column_id.$id."\n";
    $column_name = $column_name.$name."\n";
    $column_trans_id = $column_trans_id.$trans_id."\n";
    $column_amount = $column_amount.$amount."\n";

}
mysqli_close();

//Create a new PDF file
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$p->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
//Fields Name position
$Y_Fields_Name_position = 20;
//Table position, under Fields Name
$Y_Table_Position = 26;

//First create each Field Name
//Gray color filling each Field Name box
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
//Bold Font for Field Name
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(0);
$pdf->Cell(10,6,'ID',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'NAME',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(50);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'AMOUNT',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(65);

$pdf->Ln();

//Now show the  columns
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',5);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(0);
$pdf->MultiCell(10,6,$column_id,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->MultiCell(40,6,$column_name,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(50);
$pdf->MultiCell(15,6,$column_amount,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(65);

//Create lines (boxes) for each ROW (Product)
//If you don't use the following code, you don't create the lines separating each row
$i = 0;
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
while ($i < $number_of_products)
{
    $pdf->SetX(0);
    $pdf->MultiCell(65,6,'',1);
    $i = $i +1;
}
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: You deactivated the automatic page break, do you know that?

Comment: @KhorneHoly I tried having `$p->SetAutoPageBreak(true);` then does not output anything, when set as `$p->SetAutoPageBreak(false);` at least I get an output though no page break!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A5');
    $pdf->AddPage('P'); 
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode(real,'default');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $txt = file_get_contents('comments.txt', true);
    $pages = explode('~', $txt);
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $pdf->Write(8, $page);
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Some explanation based on my code would really help anyone else not just me. Kindly..